# Prolog - Recursion returns to initial state after finding desired solution

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog and I can't figure out what's wrong with my predicates. I'm trying to write a predicate that iterates over a list of vertices, like [a,b,d,f,k], and return the activities described in edge(X, vertex1, vertex2). The desired result for list [a,b,d,f,k] would be [jump, jump, fly, wow].

Because edges are bound between two vertices, I made a predicate call_act/2 that takes the first two items of a list. call_act/2 gives act/3 the full list, the second item and then awaits the result.
act/3 looks for an edge between the first item in the list and the second item and then appends it to the result.

```
edge(jump,a,b).
edge(run,a,c).
edge(jump,b,d).
edge(fly,d,f).
edge(jump,b,e).
edge(fly,c,f).
edge(run,c,g).
edge(go,d,h).
edge(sprint,e,i).
edge(flip,e,j).
edge(wow,f,k).

call_act([_|[]], _).
call_act([H,H2|T], Result) :-
    act([H,H2|T], H2, Result).

act(_,[],[_|_]).
act([H|T], Next, Result) :-
    findall(X, edge(X,H,Next), Result1),
    append(Result, Result1, ResultN),
    write(ResultN),
    nl,
    call_act(T, ResultN).
```

If you run the code like this, it will find the correct solution, but afterwards it goes back to an empty list. [Like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKJPS.png)

I have tried a couple things. I tried to stop the recursion when ResultN has a length of the full list -1, but this did not seem to work. I've tried making a modified version of act/3 that includes the final vertex as a parameter, in hopes that I could make a base case like  `act([FinalVertex|_],_,_,FinalVertex).`. But I've not figured out a solution yet.

I've also written a version of this code that merges the two predicates into one:

```
act([_|[]],_).
act([H,H2|T], Result) :-
    findall(X, edge(X,H,H2), Result1),
    append(Result, Result1, ResultN),
    write(ResultN),
    nl,
    act([H2|T], ResultN).
```

But this has the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing the following:

```
act([], []).
act([_], []).
act([V1,V2|Vs], [A|As]) :-
    edge(A, V1, V2),
    act([V2|Vs], As).
```

Example:

```
?- act([a,b,d,f,k], L).
L = [jump, jump, fly, wow] ;
false.
```